# Passing an ArrayList from Struts1.3 action to appropriate JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts1

I use Struts V1.3 for a project.
Here is my Action Class which I want to send an arrayList through request.settAttribute in execute function.

public class ProductAction extends Action {
    private List productList;

```
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
            Product product1 = new Product();
            product1.setProductName("productName1");
            product1.setProductCategory("productCategory1");
            product1.setProductPrice(15.33);
            product1.setProductDescription("productDescription1");

            Product product2 = new Product();
            product2.setProductName("productName2");
            product2.setProductCategory("productCategory2");
            product2.setProductPrice(15.454543);
            product2.setProductDescription("productDescription2");

            productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

            productList.add(product1);
            productList.add(product2);
            request.setAttribute("products", productList);
            return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

As you see I want to send an ArrayList of Product where Product is a POJO.

Here is my JSP code which I expect to get "${products}" from the Action class.

```
                    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${product.productName}</td>
                            <td>${product.productCategory}</td>
                            <td>${product.productDescription}</td>
                            <td>${product.productPrice}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

My problem is that in forEach I don't recieve anything(Even tr will not appear).
How does I can assure that I get the ArrayList in action calss in JSP?

And here is my action-mapping

```
<action name="product" path="/product" type="view.ProductAction" scope="session">
            <forward name="success" path="/productList.jsp" redirect="true"/>
            <forward name="failure" path="/success.jsp" redirect="true"/>
        </action>
```

Comment: Is your EL evaluating? What app server and version are you using?

Comment: You're **redirecting** to the JSP. So, when it's executed, it handles a request that is different from the request sent to the Struts action. Don't redirect.

Comment: @DaveNewton My webapp is web logic. the problem was redirect tag in my config-struts as Roman C mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove attribute `redirect="true"` from the forward config it makes lose of attributes required for jsp redirected.

How can you be assure about action class if it doesn' t make sense to jsp? The values are evaluated by the EL expressions and rendered by Jstl tags, so you have to make sure they are accessible in the scope of jsp. Forwarding to jsp saves the variables to request scope then you can read them in the for each tag.

Comment: Thank you very much It worked :) 
I've removed redirect tag and worked.